# Delete muliple columns from a DataTable .NET

Tags: c#, .net, datatable

I have multiple columns in a DataTable that I want to delete.  I currently have the index's I want to delete.  For example lets say I have 10 columns and I want to delete indexes 4,8 and 9.

I know I can do something like this dataTable.Columns.RemoveAt(index).  But once I do that the indexes are off for next columns I remove.

So my question is how do I delete the intended columns given the fact I only have column indexes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to avoid changing the indices of the next columns you want to remove, why not remove them in decreasing order.
For example, remove 9 then 8 then 4 instead of 4,8,9.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a few more options:

- Remove them by name:

  ```
  dataTable.Columns.Remove(col4Name);
  dataTable.Columns.Remove(col8Name);
  ```
- Get references to the columns before you remove them:

  ```
  DataColumn dc4 = dataTable.Columns[4];
  DataColumn dc8 = dataTable.Columns[8];
  DataColumn dc9 = dataTable.Columns[9];
  dataTable.Columns.Remove(dc4);
  dataTable.Columns.Remove(dc8);
  dataTable.Columns.Remove(dc9);
  ```